# How to make a Bash Loop

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

What is the best way to simplify this code and make it more functional.

```bsh
QRCode=$(cat /etc/wireguard/qr/client1)
QRCode2=$(cat /etc/wireguard/qr/client2)
QRCode3=$(cat /etc/wireguard/qr/client3)
QRCode4=$(cat /etc/wireguard/qr/client4)
QRCode5=$(cat /etc/wireguard/qr/client5)
```

I would like to make it a loop that then could be changed to any number for the desired amount of clients built. Below is the attempt, but it doesn't work.

```bsh
# Change Clients variable to create different amounts of qr codes
clients=10

counter=1
while [ $counter -le $clients ]
do
    QRCode${counter}=$(cat /etc/wireguard/qr/client${counter})
    ((counter++))
done
```

Resulting in 10 different variables (QRCode1, QRCode2, QRCode3) with 10 different values based on the files (client1, client2, client3).

Comment: Welcome, could you give more detail? Are the variables an the files names *always* incremental as shown in the example?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yes, variables are always going to be incremental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple `for` loop as

```
beg=1
end=5
for i in $(seq $beg $end)
do
    QRCode[$i]=$(cat /etc/wireguard/qr/client$i) 
done
```

This creates a bash array and you can access `i`th element as `$QRCode[$i]` or entire array by `${QRCode[*]}`.  The arrays in bash do not have to start at index 0.

Comment: I'm pulling empty variables when I later try to retrieve the contents of say, $QRCode4

Comment: @Caleb You need to use brackets and braces to index into an array (and you should also double-quote it). Like `"${QRCode[4]}"` instead of `$QRCode4`. When assigning, just use the square brackets: `QRCode[4]=somevalue`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for explaining. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an array instead of single variables, knowing how many files there are:

```bsh
declare -a QRCodes

for i in {1..10}; do 
  QRCodes[$i]="$(cat /etc/wireguard/qr/client$i)"
done
```

Then to retrieve a specific value:

```bsh
$ echo "${QRCodes[1]}"
<some value from client1 file>
```

To retrieve all the values:

```
printf "%s\n" "${QRCodes[@]}"
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Since the indexes are numeric, there's no need to use an associative array, a plain one will work fine (i.e. use `declare -a QRCodes` instead of `declare -A QRCodes`).

Comment: @GordonDavisson you are right, my first thought was in the line of what would happen if OP's needed something more sofisticated as index, but I'll update the answer with your insight.

Comment: @GordonDavisson facepalm!